# How to filter 2 object arrays and process it efficiently?

Tags: javascript, performance, typescript, ecmascript-6, filtering

I have 2 object arrays of different types with different key combinations.
How to perform efficient matching and object update for below code? I have tried different combination with .filter but no success yet.
I am updating the temporary masterList based on selectionList.

```
for (let selObj of selctionList) {
    for (let obj of masterList) {

        if (selObj['n'] == obj['name']) {
            obj['checked'] = true;
            obj['cost'] = selObj['r'];
            obj['qty'] = (selObj['q'] ? selObj['q'] : 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
for (let obj of masterList) {
    if (!obj['checked']) {
        obj['checked'] = false;
    }
}
```

Sample Data

```
`masterList = 
[{"id":459,"cost":250,"name":"Coke"},
{"id":460,"cost":60,"name":"Cookies"},
{"id":461,"cost":100,"name":"Pizza"},
{"id":462,"cost":250,"name":"Bread"},
{"id":463,"cost":150,"name":"Sausage"},
{"id":464,"cost":150,"name":"Juice"}];
selectionList = [{"q":1,"r":350,"n":"Coke"}
{"q":2,"r":550,"n":"Bread"}]`
```

Output :

```
`[{"id":459,"cost":350,"name":"Coke", "checked" : true,"qty":1},
{"id":460,"cost":60,"name":"Cookies","checked" : false},
{"id":461,"cost":100,"name":"Pizza","checked" : false},
{"id":462,"cost":550,"name":"Bread","checked" : true,"qty":2},
{"id":463,"cost":150,"name":"Sausage","checked" : false},
{"id":464,"cost":150,"name":"Juice","checked" : false}]`
```

Comment: You should add sample data, and expected result.

Comment: Add selctionList and masterList data pls

Comment: if false set false ...? the last check and update makes no sense (if it has a boolean value).

Comment: what is the sense of this: `if (!obj['checked']) {
        obj['checked'] = false;
    }` ?

Comment: I believe Anup meant if no 'checked' key is present then set to false

Comment: `(selObj['q'] ? selObj['q'] : 1);` -> `selObj['q'] || 1;`

Comment: But still need 2 objects data and expected data

Comment: `obj.checked = !!obj.checked;` cast to bool

Comment: The OP's version is easier to understand.

Comment: @OriDrori Added sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the time efficiency of this code from *O(n²)* to *O(n)* by making use of a hash map to get direct access to a `masterList` entry by its name:

```js
const masterList = [{"id":459,"cost":250,"name":"Coke"}, {"id":460,"cost":60,"name":"Cookies"}, {"id":461,"cost":100,"name":"Pizza"}, {"id":462,"cost":250,"name":"Bread"}, {"id":463,"cost":150,"name":"Sausage"}, {"id":464,"cost":150,"name":"Juice"}];
const selectionList = [{"q":1,"r":350,"n":"Coke"},{"q":2,"r":550,"n":"Bread"}];

// Create a Map to key the masterList by name
const indexed = new Map(masterList.map(o => [o.name, o]));
// First init the checked property
for (const obj of masterList) obj.checked = false;
// Then iterate and lookup in the Map.
for (const {q, r, n} of selectionList) {
    const obj = indexed.get(n); // Lookup happens in constant time 
    if (!obj) continue;
    obj.cost = r;
    obj.qty = q || 1;
    obj.checked = true;
}

console.log(masterList);
```

NB: It seems overkill to want to store a `checked` property, since matched objects already get a `qty` property which others don't have. In subsequent code you can easily check this with:

```
checked = 'qty' in obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

### A functional solution using *lodash*'s `keyBy` to speed up the calculation.

```
const masterList = [{"id":459,"cost":250,"name":"Coke"}, {"id":460,"cost":60,"name":"Cookies"}, {"id":461,"cost":100,"name":"Pizza"}, {"id":462,"cost":250,"name":"Bread"}, {"id":463,"cost":150,"name":"Sausage"}, {"id":464,"cost":150,"name":"Juice"}];
const selectionList = [{"q":1,"r":350,"n":"Coke"},{"q":2,"r":550,"n":"Bread"}];

const selectionMap = _.keyBy(selectionList, "n");
const output = masterList.map(masterItem => {
  // loop through the master list, see if we have it selected.
  const selectItem = selectionMap[masterItem.name];
  if(selectItem === undefined){
    // If it is not checked, return that information.
    return {
      ...masterItem,
      checked: false
    };
  }
  // if it is checked, return checked: true and the quantity info which defaults to 1.
  return {
    ...masterItem,
    checked: true,
    qty: selectItem['q'] || 1
  };
});

console.log(output);
```

### Output:

> ```
> [[object Object] {
>   checked: true,
>   cost: 250,
>   id: 459,
>   name: "Coke",
>   qty: 1
> }, [object Object] {
>   checked: false,
>   cost: 60,
>   id: 460,
>   name: "Cookies"
> }, [object Object] {
>   checked: false,
>   cost: 100,
>   id: 461,
>   name: "Pizza"
> }, [object Object] {
>   checked: true,
>   cost: 250,
>   id: 462,
>   name: "Bread",
>   qty: 2
> }, [object Object] {
>   checked: false,
>   cost: 150,
>   id: 463,
>   name: "Sausage"
> }, [object Object] {
>   checked: false,
>   cost: 150,
>   id: 464,
>   name: "Juice"
> }]
> ```